# using api's in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

i'm running the server using node.js on localhost:8080 and i want to use api's in my HTML document. the html document is external, so how would i go about sending the api data to the web page. for example, i have a weather api in my javascript file:

```js
var yw = require('weather-yahoo');
var ans = {};
function loadWeather() {
  yw.getSimpleWeather('denver,co').then(function(res){
      console.log(res);
      ans=res;
      alert(ans);
  }); // pulls just some of the info from yahoo weather
}
```

and i've called it on button click in my html file like so:

```html
  <button onclick="loadWeather();">View article descriptions</button>
```

but it doesn't work. i also have the included the source of the javascript file in this document by the way.

Comment: nodejs is server side - what's it doing in your browser?

Comment: running the server, using express e.g app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src', { extensions: ['html', 'css', 'js'] }));

Comment: It's little confusing! If the loadWeather() function is at server side, then you should write an API which will fork this function and call that API from your client on the button click event.

Comment: i have the weather api, i'm just not sure how to get it working on my html page. hope that makes it  clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function on your node server, but now you'll need to expose it to your client. The simplest way to do this is using the express module.

If you are not completely familiar with node modules and express, there are plenty of startup tutorials available such as [https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html.](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

In your case you would need to create an API call that will call the weather data function.

```
var app = require('express')(),
yw = require('weather-yahoo');

function loadWeather() {
   return yw.getSimpleWeather('denver,co');
}

app.get('/weather', function(req, res){
    loadWeather().then(function(result){
        return res.json(result);
    }, 
    function(error){
        res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/index.html', null, function(err) {
        if(err){
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });

})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
})
```

This is the simplest of API calls that can easily be extended to return weather for other regions by adding query parameters to the api call.

On the client side, you will now need a function to call your api.
As the example above serves the index file as it's main page, a simple JQuery get call to **weather** will return the data you want as it is on the same host.

```
<script>
    //This call uses JQuery, make sure you have it referenced in your site
    function callAPI() {
        $.get("weather", function(data, status){
            $('#result').val(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
</script>

<button onclick="callAPI()">Get Weather</button>
<br>
<textarea id="result" style="width:500px; height:500px"></textarea>
```

Comment: Assuming that you have everything setup as in my example, if you add this url to the browser, do you get the data back?

http://localhost:3000/weather

Comment: yeah i get the data back, it just doesn't display in the textarea.

Comment: Two things to check. 
The first is that the page is loaded through the server rather than just from the file system. Just  navigate to localhost:3000 to ensure this.
What url shows up in the network debugger when you click the button?

The second is that you have JQuery referenced.

Comment: yeah, works fine but mine is on 8080. nothing shows up in the url apart from the localhost:8080

Comment: Assuming your server is also on port 8080, in the JQuery get, change it to include the full url just as a check.
 
$.get("http://localhost:8080/weather" ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139573/discussion-between-matt-gordon-and-colonelxo).

Comment: The conclusion to the chat was that JQuery was not referenced.